# Spring boot convert timestamp to UTC but when fetch from database converts to server time

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, timestamp, jpa-2.0

I have two questions.

1) I want to want convert timestamp (only timestamp and not java.util.Date) to UTC time before insert into database and when run select query wants to get as it is in the database for eg:

My JVM time is set to IST when I insert 01-01-2019 00:00:00 (primitive data type timestamp) into the database value updated in the database is 31-12-2018 18:30:00 but when I fetch the same using JPA by default it converts time to 01-01-2019 00:00:00 while giving output.

I want that time should be by default converted to UTC while inserting into the database but while fetching from the database it should give me what is inserted into the database no conversion from JVM.

I have added below code in the application properties file

setting timezone to UTC for database

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = UTC

2) One more thing I encounter it also convert java.util.Date to UTC 31-12-2018 from 01-01-2019 00:00 00 IST (primitive data type java.util.Date) I don't want conversion of java.util.Date 01-01-2019 should go as 01-01-2019 in the database.

> This should not convert

```
@Column(name = "openingDate", nullable = false)
private Date openingDate;
```

> This should convert to UTC

```
@Column(insertable = true, updatable = false, name = "createdDate")
private Timestamp createdDate;
```

Project details: Spring boot Gradle JPA

I have referred below URL for setting database date to UTC [link](https://moelholm.com/2016/11/09/spring-boot-controlling-timezones-with-hibernate/)

Comment: So when you store `01-01-2019 00:00:00` into the database, you want to retrieve it as `31-12-2018 18:30:00`? Why? Also, it seems you are using the date part only? Would it be worth considering using a date without time of day? `LocalDate` in Java and `date` in most SQL databases.

Comment: @OleV.V. In the database it is stored as 31-12-2018:18:30:00 but when I run the select query using JPA it converts back to IST since my JVM is set to Indian Standard Time, I want time as 31-12-2018:18:30:00 in select output

Comment: @OleV.V. I have added one more question for conversion of primitive data type java.util.Date (date type should go as it is in database without conversion)